# How can I measure amount of data (internet data) my python script uses?

Tags: python, measure

```
    uClient = uReq(test_url)
    testpage_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
```

This is the part of the script that I want to be measured. How much internet data does this process take. If anyone has a way to do it, please share:) Thank you a lot

Comment: what's uReq ? Also python should be - mostly - snakecase, not camelcase.
Please read PEP-8 <3
Also see : https://linuxhint.com/network_usage_per_process/

Comment: from urllib.request import  urlopen as uReq

Comment: By `internet data` do you mean all transferred bytes in the entire transaction?  You already know the number of bytes in the html page.